# connect device to worklight console

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

i have downloaded the pushnotification example from the ibm website and running it in my eclipse

```
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.90.33.127:10080 refused
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    06-29 11:12:45.952: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.90.33.127 (port 10080) after 10000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871):     ... 9 more
    06-29 11:12:45.962: W/System.err(8871): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    06-29 11:12:45.972: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    06-29 11:12:45.972: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    06-29 11:12:45.972: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
    06-29 11:12:45.972: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    06-29 11:12:45.972: W/System.err(8871):     ... 14 more
    06-29 11:12:46.032: D/wl.certManager(8871): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
    06-29 11:12:46.072: W/PluginManager(8871): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.deleteAllAuthData blocked the main thread for 36ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    06-29 11:12:46.082: D/wl.certManager(8871): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
    06-29 11:12:46.162: W/PluginManager(8871): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 87ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.90.33.127:10080 refused
    06-29 11:12:46.172: D/wl.request(8871): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.90.33.127:10080/PushNotifications/authorization/v1/clients/instance
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)
    06-29 11:12:46.172: W/System.err(8871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.90.33.127 (port 10080) after 10000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at         java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871):     ... 9 more
    06-29 11:12:46.182: W/System.err(8871): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    06-29 11:12:46.192: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    06-29 11:12:46.192: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    06-29 11:12:46.192: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
    06-29 11:12:46.192: W/System.err(8871):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    06-29 11:12:46.192: W/System.err(8871):     ... 14 more
    06-29 11:12:46.262: D/wl.certManager(8871): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
    06-29 11:12:46.272: D/NONE(8871): Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":500,"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.","invocationContext":null}
    06-29 11:12:46.332: E/NONE(8871): [/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
    06-29 11:12:46.352: D/NONE(8871): Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server.
    06-29 11:12:46.762: W/PluginManager(8871): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Notification.confirm blocked the main thread for 403ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

here are details of my mobilefirst server

host name:10.90.33.127

and my adpater details

```
    wlServerProtocol = http
    wlServerHost = 10.90.33.127
    wlServerPort = 10080
    wlServerContext = /PushNotifications/
    wlAppId = PushNotifications
```

and the error on my device says "failed connecting to the mobilefirst server.Try again later".

and my wlclient.properties is

```
     wlServerProtocol = http
     wlServerHost = 10.90.33.127
     wlServerPort = 10080
     wlServerContext = /PushNotifications/
     wlAppId = PushNotifications
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to 10.90.33.127:10080/worklightconsole, do you actually see the console in a desktop browser?

If you do the same from your mobile device, do you also see the console?

It sounds like your mobile device is not connected to the same network as your server. If you are testing in a local environment, make sure your mobile device is connected to the same wifi network as your computer.

Comment: 1) yes i am able to see console in my computer     2)no i am unable to visit the console over my phone (its says web page is unavailable)     3) yes i am connected to the same network

Comment: Is there any way to check how my app is connecting to the server like which url it is connecting?

Comment: In your android app find the wlclient.propeties file, or in iOS the worklight.plist file. This file is available in the **generated project** (native folder after you build the app in Studio); that's the address it gets in order to connect to the server. Your IP is probably the wrong one.

Comment: the client also has the same address... i have edited the question